# Use javascript to fill up dropdown textbox and then click it

Tags: javascript, css

I have a drop down textbox which I want to write "arterial line", then wait for 1000ms and then emulate a mouse click over the highlighted item (shown below) using Javascript
[Drop down textbox screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dljip.jpg)

CSS selector for the textbox is

```
.ng-select-opened > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)
```

Please guide me on how to do this withn a single code.

**EDIT:**

For emulating the mouse click, I have this code

> document.querySelector('[class="ng-option
> ng-option-marked"]').click();

I just need the code to fill up the textbox for that CSS value in question, then wait, then do the click.

Comment: Please provide the `html` and `javascript` code as in  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: For emulating the mouse click ```document.querySelector('[class="ng-option ng-option-marked"]').click();```, I just need the code to fill up the textbox for that CSS value in question, then wait, then do the click. Please help

Comment: then you can use [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function

Comment: the fill up code: `document.querySelector('.ng-select-opened > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)').value = 'arterial line'`
[input.value](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp)

Comment: Thank you, I have got one more problem. The CSS value keeps on changing. Can we use pattern matching for selecting the CSS value while doing ```document.querySelector('.ng-select-opened > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)').value = 'arterial line'```. This part ```> div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)``` of the CSS value is constant, the part prior this keeps on changing